openpyxl-find and select 3 row header range
I'm trying to find and select a range of cells over three rows that contain values I want to convert to a headers and I'm having trouble selecting that range.
I attached the Jupyter Notebook. It goes through multiple workbooks and worksheets, but my challenge is in trying to get selected_range in the definition of the process_spreadsheet function. I am trying to do so by iterate through the cells in column A looking for a cell with a particular fill color, then iterate through cells towards the right to find the last cell with that color. If there's a better way, I am all ears.
The issue begins prior to line 51:
start_min_col, start_min_row, end_max_col, end_max_row = range_boundaries(selected_range)

selected_range is a string, but start_min_col, ... ,end_max_row are NoneType objects, but they must be int for the remaining code to execute without error.
openpyxl.utils.cell.range_boundaries(range_string): Convert a range string into a tuple of boundaries: (min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row) Cell coordinates will be converted into a range with the cell at both end.
I dont see a way to attach my ipynb. Please let me know if I should put it somewhere accessible.
pip install pandas openpyxl xlrd

import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import range_boundaries

def process_spreadsheet(file_path):
    # Load the workbook
    wb = load_workbook(file_path, data_only=True)
    data = []

    for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[sheet_name]
        
        # Add the spreadsheet name and tab name to the data list
        data.append([os.path.basename(file_path), sheet_name])
        
        # Define the RGB color for gray
        gray_fill = "00D9D9D9"  # This is the hex code for gray

        selected_range = ""
      
        # Iterate through cells in column A
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
            cell = row[0]
            # Check if the cell has a fill type and if it's gray
            if cell.fill and cell.fill.fgColor and cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == "00D9D9D9":
                start_cell = cell.coordinate  # The coordinate of the first gray cell in column A

                # Iterate to the right until a cell without fill type is found
                for col in range(2, ws.max_column + 1):
                    current_cell = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=col)
                    if not current_cell.fill or not current_cell.fill.fgColor or current_cell.fill.fgColor.rgb != "00D9D9D9":
                        end_col = col - 1  # The last column with gray fill
                        break
                else:
                    end_col = ws.max_column  # If all cells to the right are filled, take the last column

                # Define the range (from first gray cell in column A to the last gray cell to the right, and two rows down)
                end_cell = ws.cell(row=cell.row + 2, column=end_col).coordinate
                selected_range = f"{start_cell}:{end_cell}"

                # Get the range boundaries

        start_min_col, start_min_row, end_max_col, end_max_row = range_boundaries(selected_range)
        
        # Unmerge and process merged cells within the selected range
        for merged_range in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
            min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(str(merged_range))

            # Check if the merged range is within our selected range
            if (
                min_row >= start_min_row and max_row <= end_max_row and
                min_col >= start_min_col and max_col <= end_max_col
            ):
                # If merged horizontally, unmerge and copy value across the cells
                if min_row == max_row:
                    merged_value = ws.cell(row=min_row, column=min_col).value
                    ws.unmerge_cells(str(merged_range))
                    for col in range(min_col, max_col + 1):
                        ws.cell(row=min_row, column=col, value=merged_value)
                # If merged vertically, just unmerge
                elif min_col == max_col:
                    ws.unmerge_cells(str(merged_range))            
        
        # Concatenate values of the first three rows of each column in the selected range
        concatenated_values = []
        for col in range(start_min_col, end_max_col + 1):
            values = [
                ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value or ""  # Handle None values
                for row in range(start_min_row, start_min_row + 3)
            ]
            concatenated_string = " ".join(str(v) for v in values)
            concatenated_values.append(concatenated_string)
        
        # Add the list of concatenated strings to the data list
        data.append(concatenated_values)

    return data

def process_directory(source_dir, output_file):
    data = []

    for file_name in os.listdir(source_dir):
        #if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
        file_path = os.path.join(source_dir, file_name)
        data.extend(process_spreadsheet(file_path))

    # Create a DataFrame and save it to a CSV file
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Spreadsheet Name', 'Tab Name'] + ['Header' + str(i+1) for i in range(len(data[0]) - 2)])
    df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source_dir = 'FeeScheduleNew'
    output_file = 'FSHeaders.csv'
    process_directory(source_dir, output_file)

Excel files:Texas Medicaid & Healthcare Partnerships (TMPH) Fee Schedules

The files I looked at all have 24 lines of comments and then start at line 25, with a 3-row header.
You can load the file with pandas directly like:
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel('FeeSchedules.xls', sheet_name=0, skiprows=24, header=[0,1,2])`

skiprows skips the 24 rows of comments, and header=[0,1,2] sets the header to be made from the first 3 rows.
Then you need to clean up the index a little, but you got the data in 1 line of code.
